# How do I find the size of tokenizer<char_separator<char>>

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace boost;

Vibranium::MySQLConnectionInfo::MySQLConnectionInfo(Config& config, const std::string &connectionDetails) {
    char_separator<char> sep{";"};
    tokenizer<char_separator<char>> tokens(connectionDetails,sep);
}
```

How do I find how many elements I have in `tokens` ?

Because I want to do something like this:

```
if (tokens.size() != 5 && tokens.size() != 6)
    return;
```

So if the size is not as described to stop the execution. However `.size()` is not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have a size because it doesn't contain tokens – it tokenizes as you iterate over it, "delivering" tokens into an iterator.

You can copy the tokens into something, and then check what you got.

```
std::vector<std::string> actual_tokens(tokens.begin(), tokens.end());
```

If you're only interested in how many tokens there are and not what they are, you can use `std::distance(tokens.begin(), tokens.end())`.
If there can be many more than six, you might want to use a manual loop so you don't have to iterate over all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::distance` :

```
boost::char_separator<char> sep{";"};
std::string str = "1;2;3;4;5";
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(str,sep);
std::cout << std::distance(tokens.begin(), tokens.end());
// outputs 5
```